# background-color on heading with pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, background-color, pseudo-element, css-content

I am trying to make a heading with a trailing bar. I used the pseudo-element `::after`.

My problem is the background color of the heading should "block out" the part of the `::after` element that is located "under" the heading itself - but it doesn't.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h3>TEST</h3>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <h3>TEST 2</h3>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Arial;
}
div{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h3{
    font-size: 200%;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
h3::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1.3rem;
    background: hsl(200, 30%, 20%);
    margin-top: -1.7rem;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianemilius/s0v1h59m/)

Comment: can u post a screenshot of what you are looking for??

Comment: You want the after background-color to be behind the default h3 background-color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the pseudo-element absolutely...it's also cleaner css.

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s0v1h59m/7/)

**CSS**

```
body{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h3{
    font-size: 200%;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h3::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: hsl(200, 30%, 20%);
```

}

Comment: Paulie, I am accepting your answer cause it actually answers my question instead of providing alternative solutions :)
Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: You are welcome but **James Donnelly** is not wrong so you might want to upvote that answer too...even if you chose to accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much simpler (and support a wider range of browsers) for you to just wrap your text within a `span` element:

```
<h3><span>TEST</span></h3>
```

And then give your `h3` element a `block` display with the required background colour, then give your `span` element an `inline-block` display with the overlay colour:

```css
h3{
    font-size: 200%;
    background: hsl(200, 30%, 20%);
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

h3 span {
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s0v1h59m/5/).

You can then offset this by giving your `span` element the desired `padding`.

Comment: I agree..much simpler. One thing..aren't headings `display:block` by default?